# fish alias with a variable in the middle?

Tags: command-line, alias, fish

I have dyslexia so I use fish as my shell since it's great with prediction, correction and aliasing.  I'm trying to figure out how to make an alias with a variable inside followed by the rest of the alias.

Example:
Right now I have alias `ppa="sudo add-apt-repository"`.  I can just type `ppa` then copy the repo's *ppa:foo-bar/ppa* afterward and end up with `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:foo-bar/ppa`

This is convenient enough, so if this next part would be too difficult or plain ol' impossible to do, no worries.

I'd like to amend this alias to `ppa="sudo add-apt-repository"` ; upd`(where upd is also aliased as`upd="sudo apt update"`).  Is there a way I can do this?  In case I'm not being clear enough, here's what I'd like to do with the cli in this case:

alias with variable: 
`$ ppa [variable]`
decoded alias with variable: 
`$ sudo sudo add-apt-repository [variable] ; upd`

Example as above:
alias with variable: 
`$ ppa ppa:foo-bar/ppa`
decoded alias with variable: 
`$ sudo sudo add-apt-repository ppa:foo-bar/ppa ; upd`

Is there a way to do this?  Again, if not or if its way too complicate for what it's worth, no problem.

Thanks a lot!  I appreciate it!

〜 Ev

PS -- If anyone would like me to help them make their own aliases for commands they enter all the time and wish to do so using fish, feel free to ask.  I'd be glad to help!

Comment: You don't accept answers to many of your questions. You might want to read https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't do this with a fish alias. But fish functions are much better:

```
function upd
    sudo apt update
end
funcsave upd

function ppa
    sudo add-apt-repository $argv
    upd
end
funcsave ppa
```

Copy and paste this into your terminal
and you should be good to go.

Keep in mind that

```
alias foo=bar
```

is simply a shortcut for

```
function foo; bar $argv; end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, so probably no use to OP, but this can be done *almost* as the OP wants, and perhaps even something that is more useful.

Fish has [abbreviations](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/abbr.html), which I prefer to aliases or functions whenever possible because:

1. The actual command is shown, so that I still remember what the *actual* command is, which is useful when getting a new computer, new job, or using someone else's computer.
2. It has `--set-cursor`, which acts as a "cursor-infix", which solves the OP's problem.

### `abbr` with `--set-cursor`

I work with multiple Kubernetes namespaces (environments), but 90% of the time with our dev namespace, that we call `hot-deploy`. So I have made an abbreviation to always add the namespace:

```bash
abbr -a k --set-cursor -- "kubectl % -n hot-deploy"
```

This enables me to just type the letter `k` (and a space) and the following command comes out, ***with the cursor between `kubectl` and `-n`***:

```bash
kubectl <CURSOR HERE> -n hot-deploy
```

I have done this with a bunch of other abbreviations, too, and even a trick so that the cursor is at the end of what I type, after hitting the space:

```bash
abbr -a rep --set-cursor -- "cd /home/mike-williamson/repos/myapp/%"
```

By putting the `%` at the end, this means that after typing `rep` + space, it will output:

```bash
cd /home/mike-williamson/repos/myapp/<CURSOR HERE>
```

This then lets me type `rep` + space, then immediately type `fro` + tab and it will will in `frontend` (or type whatever to get me to a sub-directory I want to go to).

I use abbreviations so heavily that I sometimes need to use `abbr -l` to list all of them, because I've forgotten them all.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a script for that and make the alias call the script. Something like this (untested):
add_ppa_and_update.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Take first argument and use it to add the repository
add-apt-repository $1
# Update
apt update
```

Now give the script run permissions `sudo chmod 755 add_ppa_and_update.sh` and create an alias that calls the script with sudo `sudo add_ppa_and_update.sh [variable]`.

Comment: c'mon. This is like answering a python question with a perl answer.